# Text parsing library

Tags: parsing, syntax, abstract-syntax-tree

A colleague of mine works on an universal text parsing library, based on C# lambdas. The core looks cool, but unfortunately to me he has hardcoded a grammar, specifical to his private task -- math expression evaluating. So, I will not use it as I had intended before I saw the API. And now I'm looking for another lib, that meets at least some of my requirements. It has to:

1. Be able to load a grammar from an external file -- say, XML, [YML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yml) or JSON.
2. Return AST from grammar and parsed tree that is built from any text.
3. Work fast enough to load C# grammar then parse a large code file.

I'd prefer the library that has grammar format file simple enough for easy writing a grammar for math expressions, is open source and written in C# or C++.

Regards,

--
UPDATED: point 2 has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [Text Transformer](http://www.texttransformer.com/) which claims to be some kind of universal text processing language.    I have no specific experience with it.

Building robust langauge front ends and usable processing tools is actually a lot of work.
If you want to process computer languages in a generic way, you might consider our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html), a kind of generalized compiler technology for parsing, analyzing, transforming, and/or generating code (or any other kind of formal document).

DMS will accept arbitrary context free grammars for langauges, automatically builds an AST with no additional specification effort on your part, and is designed to handle not only large files but very large sets of files in a single computation.   Normally people
that want to process code need pattern recognition, code analysis and code transformation capabilities; DMS has all of these built in.   It also has a variety of predefined, mature grammars for a wide variety of computer langauges, well-known (C, C++, C#, COBOL, Java, JavaScript, ... ) and otherwise (Natural, EGL, Python, MATLAB, ...), and has been used to carry out massive automated analyses and transformations on programs in these various langauges.

DMS does not meet your open-source or C#/C++ implementation requirements.  It is implemented as a set of domain-specific langauges for describing grammars, analyzers, transformations, prettyprinters, and scripting that allows parallel execution to enable complex analyses to run faster than single-threaded programs.

Comment: First off, thank you for your answer! Now let me ask you: these toolkits look nice, but what about library that can be a part of my software and lets to load a grammar in run-time? I want to have possibility to update my products just replacing the grammar files without recompiling whole projects. Otherwise I'd just use MS Irony (it forces to describe a grammar in C#, not in a marked up data file).

Comment: @noober: Building these engines is hard. I don't know how long TextTransformer took to engineer; I know that DMS has about a man-century of engineering behind it (I'm the architect). It would be nice if one could organize them to be some library, but everybody has a different desired langauge they want to call the library from and as a result you make at most one set of possible users happy. (I get flak from Ruby programmers that DMS isn't Ruby library. I just laugh). If you insist on a C++ or C# callable library, you'll have to look at other tools. ...

Comment: @noober: ... TextTransformer may have a C++ interface.  You might consider ANTLR, which I think has a C++ version (dunno about C#) but it won't build ASTs for you automatically; you may not care since there is a claimed C# parser for ANTLR.   You might consider Stratego, which can be accessed as a Java library, and I think there is a claimed C# parser (and AST builder) for it already too. ...

Comment: @noober: ... but what you should think about, IMHO, is how much effort it takes to *process* the ASTs once you get them, to do something interesting.  This is where tools like DMS (and Stratego to a lesser extent) provide a huge advantage over "ok, I got my parse to work (whew!) and now I need..." all kinds of stuff that parsers don't supply: symbol table management, attribute grammars, flow analyzers, transformation machinery, AST-to-text regeneration, ... you really don't want to implement that all yourself.  You can try, but in general you won't finish.